# Jenkins cannot curl to a http endpoint host on a docker container

Tags: curl, docker, jenkins, centos

I am trying to build a docker container and run my integration test against the same built container using jenkins.

The issue i'm currently having is I can build and run the container and when I try to do a curl to the http end point i get a connection refuse. So I believe it is something to do with my jenkins slave configuration. I have added the jenkins user to `wheel docker jenkins` group and when i run the curl command logged as jenkins it works. But when i run it from jenkins I am getting a connection refuse.

```
    JenkinsFile 
    sh "docker build -t my-service ."
    sh "docker rm -f my-service || true"
    sh "docker run -d -p 9091:5000 -p 1433:1433 --name=my-service my-service"
    sh "docker ps"
    sh "curl -v http://172.16.32.20:9091/api/products/"
```

Jenkins output

```
+ curl -v http://172.16.32.20:9091/api/products/baggingoptions
* About to connect() to 172.16.32.20 port 9091 (#0)
*   Trying 172.16.32.20...
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  
 Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     
  0* Connection refused
  * Failed connect to 172.16.32.20:9091; Connection refused
  * Closing connection 0
 curl: (7) Failed connect to 172.16.32.20:9091; Connection refused
```

Slave info:

```
Static hostname: **************************
     Icon name: computer-vm
       Chassis: vm
    Machine ID: 009cdec7fded4740be96692dfee788c0
       Boot ID: fe492def29c047bf910c213911fda980
Virtualization: vmware
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
   CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
        Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
  Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: why are you mapping two ports? your service runs on two different ports (5000 and 1433)?

Comment: my application needs both of these ports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a docker run, it may take some time for the server to startup, but you immediately try to connect. Also possible causes are that a firewall blocks requests, the ip address of your server is not static or that the docker service itself fails. There is not enough information to have a conclusive answer.

Comment: that was the issue, thanks. I increased the wait timeout and it worked

Comment: I also got successfull with sleeping for some seconds after the server start and then do curl

Answer (score 0):

Just add delay before executing curl (or add retry in curl cmd) : docker doesn't load the container so quickly :)